# SQL: Delete all nested self referencing records

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

This is the structure of a table: `Id   Name   ParentId`

`ParentId` is a foreign key to primary column `Id`. Now lets say I have a few rows like: (Only showing `ParentId` from rows)

```
     01
   /    \
  5      2
        / \
       3   4
```

I have setup `InsteadOfDelete` trigger as seen below:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_tb] ON [dbo].[Some_tb]
    INSTEAD OF DELETE 
AS 
    /*Delete from another table*/
    DELETE FROM SomeOther_tb WHERE OtherId IN(SELECT Id FROM deleted);

    /*Delete childs from this table*/
    DELETE FROM Some_tb WHERE ParentId IN(SELECT Id FROM deleted);

    /*Delete from this table*/
    DELETE FROM Some_tb WHERE Id IN(SELECT Id FROM deleted);
```

When record with `Id = 01` (check representation of childs above) is deleted. Only immediate childs (`Id=5,2`) are deleted leaving behind sub-child records (`Id = 3,4`).

I am assuming `InsteadOfTrigger` functions are not triggered for childs (`Id=5,2`).

How do I solve this issue, such that all the nested childrens are deleted?

Comment: Why not leverage cascading deletes since that seems to be exactly what you are doing?

Comment: Can't because of multiple cascade path: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2733/solving-the-sql-server-multiple-cascade-path-issue-with-a-trigger/

Comment: So this is a self-joining table?

Comment: Yes, in a way. `ParentId` references `Id` from the same table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @DELETED TABLE(
        Id BIGINT
    );


WITH LoopCTE AS (
  SELECT Id, ParentId,0 AS steps
  FROM dbo.Some_tb
  WHERE Id IN (SELECT Id FROM deleted)

  UNION ALL

  SELECT mgr.Id, mgr.ParentId, parent.steps +1 AS steps
  FROM LoopCTE AS parent
    INNER JOIN dbo.Some_tb AS mgr
      ON parent.Id = mgr.ParentId
)
INSERT INTO @DELETED SELECT Id FROM LoopCTE AS u;

/*Delete from another table*/
DELETE FROM SomeOther_tb WHERE OtherId IN(SELECT Id FROM @DELETED);


/*Delete childs from this table*/  <-- No longer required
/*DELETE FROM Some_tb WHERE ParentId IN(SELECT Id FROM @DELETED);*/

/*Delete from this table*/
DELETE FROM Some_tb WHERE Id IN(SELECT Id FROM @DELETED);
```

Comment: there is no need in `@deleted` table

Comment: @AlexKudryashev Then how to insert the new `Ids` that have been found by CTE? UNION with deleted?

Comment: You don't need to **insert** them. Use CTE directly to `delete` what you want.

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_tb] ON [dbo].[Some_tb]
    INSTEAD OF DELETE 
AS 
    DECLARE @DELETED TABLE(
        ID BIGINT
    )

    INSERT INTO @DELETED
        SELECT Id FROM deleted

    --could use a CTE here as well for better performance
    WHILE @@ROWCOUNT>0
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO @DELETED
                SELECT Id
                FROM Some_tb t
                inner join @DELETED d on d.parentid=t.id
        END

    /*Delete from another table*/
    DELETE FROM SomeOther_tb WHERE OtherId IN(SELECT Id FROM @DELETED);

    /*Delete childs from this table*/
    DELETE FROM Some_tb WHERE ParentId IN(
       SELECT Id FROM @DELETED WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM DELETED)
    );

    /*Delete from this table*/
    DELETE FROM Some_tb WHERE Id IN(SELECT Id FROM DELETED);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I did try some CTE stuff and wrote an answer of my own. Would really appreciate your inputs/suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

MS SQL Server 2008 supports Common Table Expressions (CTE) which are great for hierarchical data. And CTE may exist in trigger as well.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_tb] ON [dbo].[Some_tb]
    INSTEAD OF DELETE 
AS 
    /*Delete from another table*/
    ;with tbl as (--this is CTE
      --anchor query (top level)
      select t.id, t.parentid
      from someOther_tb t
      inner join deleted d on d.id = t.parentid
      union all
      --recursive query
      select t.id, t.parentid
      from someOther_tb t
      inner join tbl on tbl.id=t.parentid
    )
    delete someOther_tb
    where id in (select id from tbl)        

    --Now it is safe to delete from main table
    DELETE FROM Some_tb WHERE Id IN(SELECT Id FROM deleted)
```

Comment: Thanks Alex, I guess `from someOther_tb` is not right here as `ParentId` and `Id` are from same table. Btw I added an answer with CTE implementation. Do let me know your opinion about it.

Comment: Do you mean that `some_tb` and `someOther_tb` (as in OP) are the same table?

Comment: The aim here is to remove all the nested childs of `Some_tb` including records from `SomeOther_tb` that are referenced with `Some_tb`.

The problem as described in question is that all nested childs were not deleted.

Comment: As you see in my answer they are deleted now. If `someOther_tb` has its own hierarchical structure then it is enough to pick top level `id`'s in **anchor query**.

Comment: Sorry but I am not able to understand your answer. Anyways, I have upvoted it.